# Why autofocus not working on opened modal that created by flowbite modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, flowbite

I am trying to use autofocus functionality in my input area. I have a modal open when I click on a button. Inside modal component I have a input area that created using **react-hook-forms** for validation. I tried to use **useRef** to check if my modal rendered, after render completed, I am trying to use autofocus using **setFocus** from **react-hook-forms** but it is not working.

Here my some part of my code

```js
export const FileListContextModal = <InputName extends string>({
  inputProps: { defaultValue, ...inputProps },
  title,
  onClose,
  onSubmit,
  cancelLabel,
  saveLabel,
  ...modalProps
}: FileListContextModalProps<InputName>) => {
  const { handleSubmit, control, setError, setFocus } = useForm<
    Record<string, string>
  >({
    defaultValues: { [inputProps.name]: defaultValue || '' },
  });

  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      setFocus(inputProps.name);
    }
  }, [inputRef]);

  return (
    <Modal {...modalProps} onClose={onClose} onClick={preventPropagation}>
      <Modal.Header>{title}</Modal.Header>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
        <Modal.Body>
          <FormTextInput control={control} {...inputProps} ref={inputRef} />
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button type="button" color="light" onClick={onClose}>
            {cancelLabel}
          </Button>
          <Button type="submit">{saveLabel}</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

as you see it is not focusing in my input area
[image]

I used **setTimeOut** inside **useEffect** but I dont know how much it is right to give time and focus on the input area after a while. Here the working code snippet

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
   setFocus(inputProps.name);
    }, 5);
  }, [setFocus, inputProps.name]);
```

Is there any other solution other than using setTimeOut here ??

Comment: and what about the autofocus attribute on the input field? I think it should work without JS

Comment: @ArtemKh you mean usage like that 
          <FormTextInput control={control} {...inputProps} autoFocus />
I tried it but this usage also not works

Comment: In that case try to use useLayoutEffect instead useEffect

Comment: @ArtemKh unfortunately it does not work. My modal using react portal. can it stem from that ?